# How to get top users from assignment

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am building a Rails 5.0 app.

In this app I got three models, User, Feedback and Assignment.

When a user adds one or more receivers to a Feedback object that he or she creates an assignment is created to hold this connection.

**User**

```
User(id: integer, account_id: integer, fullname:string)
```

**Feedback**

```
Feedback(id: integer, account_id: integer, user_id: integer, title: string, ftype: string, badge: string, category: string, privacy: string, anonymous: boolean, description: text, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)

create_table "feedbacks", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "account_id"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.string   "title"
    t.string   "ftype",       default: "provided"
    t.string   "badge"
    t.string   "category"
    t.string   "privacy"
    t.boolean  "anonymous",   default: false
    t.text     "description"
    t.datetime "created_at",                       null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                       null: false
    t.index ["account_id"], name: "index_feedbacks_on_account_id", using: :btree
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_feedbacks_on_user_id", using: :btree
  end
```

**Assignment**

```
Assignment(id: integer, account_id: integer, user_id: integer, assignable_type: string, assignable_id: integer, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime) 

create_table "assignments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "account_id"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.string   "assignable_type"
    t.integer  "assignable_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",      null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",      null: false
    t.index ["account_id"], name: "index_assignments_on_account_id", using: :btree
    t.index ["assignable_type", "assignable_id"], name: "index_assignments_on_assignable_type_and_assignable_id", using: :btree
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_assignments_on_user_id", using: :btree
  end
```

How can I get the top five receivers of feedback?

Comment: Could you provide the association schema?

Comment: Updated it now above.

Comment: `assignable_id` in `Assignment` related to reciever, right?

Comment: assignable_id is related to Feedback object (assignment can be used with other objects like comments too). user_id is related to the receiver.

Comment: And you want to get top 5 users who have most of all assignment?

Comment: Yes true. The users that have received most feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to define how many assigments each user have:

```
Assignment.group(:user_id).count
```

It will return hash `{1 => "10", 2 => "15", ...}`

Then sort it and extract first 5 elemnts.

```
ids = Assignment.group(:user_id).count.sort_by{|_, v| -v}.first(5).map{|id, _| id}
```

It will return you id of appropriate users.

Then just find user by ids.

```
users = User.where(id: ids)
```

Comment: Will I get User objects in return then?

Comment: mm, gets NameError: undefined local variable or method `k' for main:Object

Comment: Typo. Put `id` instead of `k`

Comment: Seems to work. Thank you! Is it possible to make it one query?

Comment: Yes. You can join your `users` and `assigmnets` tables. But it will be more lightweight to do it in two separate queries.

Comment: One last thing. I need to get the count as a variable so that I can display it in the JSON output (I am using the data to setup a graph).

Comment: `Assignment.group(:user_id).count` will return hash where keys are users ids, values - count of assigments: `{1 => "10", 2 => "15", ...}`

Comment: Yes, not sure how to return with though so that I can access it in Jbuilder file

Comment: I needed to get assignable_type (Feedback) into the query too so I added .where(assignable_type: "Feedback") and it seems to work but I need to get the count accessible in jbuilder to in order to make this done.

Comment: Insert appropriate `.where(...)` before `.group`: `Assignment.where(...your condition...).group(:user_id).count`